# $ \int \frac{dx}{4x^2-12x+13}$

Tags: integration, analysis

This is probably not too hard but i can't get it right:

I am trying to calculate $$\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{4x^2-12x+13}$$.

The solution is $\displaystyle \frac{-1}{4}tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{2}-x)+c$, but I don't know how to get there.

I know that $tan^{-1}dx = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$, which is probably important for the solution.
I tried substitution here but it is giving me $$\displaystyle\frac{log(4x^2-12x+13)}{8x-12}$$ 
(I substituted for the whole $z = 4x^2-12x+13$).

Can anybody please give me a hint how to get to the correct term? Substitution rule is probably the way to go, but i think i don't have a feeling of how to do a correct substitution yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track! Complete the square in the bottom and then pattern match your integral to arctangent. You'll get $4x^2-12x+13 = (2x-3)^2+4$. Now introduce $u = 2x-3$, $du = 2dx$ to transform your integral $$\int \frac{dx}{4x^2-12x+13} = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{u^2+4} $$ from here you need to do some algebra to get  $$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{u^2+4} = c\int \frac{d(\text{variable})}{(a\cdot \text{variable})^2+1}$$ where $a,c$ are constants, and from there you can get $$c\int \frac{d(\text{variable})}{(a\cdot \text{variable})^2+1} = \frac{c}{a}\arctan(a\cdot \text{variable})+D$$ You could do a second substitution to get what I called "variable" but this problem is also possible to solve so that $u =$ variable

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $4x^2-12x+13=(2x-3)^2+2^2,$

using [Trigonometric substitution](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html), set $2x-3=2\tan\theta$

Comment: @Falco In your book's answer there is a negative x-term, which is through the chain rule compensated with a negative upfront. Not sure why the author would do that. Using La's method, you won't have those negatives. Also, in YOUR approach, you cannot compensate the chanrule by using the variable...:)